# Regex First Instance Of Everything Between Slashes

Tags: regex

**/pig/latin/**

Heres context for it:
http://www.mysite.com/pig/latin/

I've got a value that contains /pig/latin/ or it could be /pig/latin/is/great

I need just the pig portion. How is this done?
Could you also explain the pattern a bit

Comment: -1 Could you explain your question a bit? What are the constraints? Is it only ever words? Will there ever be more than three slashed etc etc. Help us help you.

Comment: Maybe this will help `^.*\/(\w+)\/`, but please make your question clearer and maybe avoid words like "pig" ...

Comment: This won't even work on his only example... @HamZaDzCyberDeV

Comment: @Loamhoof My bad :P `^.*?\/(\w+)\/`

Comment: So are you looking for the first block of text that comes after your domain name?  Or will this always be matching a relative path?  What language are you performing the regex with?  JavaScript?

Comment: Hey guys, lesson learned (be more specific) . Yes as you can see by my example, I am basically working with magento (php) and constructing my own routing to bake in a custom view. I need to check and make sure that the first part matches a particular string and then if that string is matched trigger an action in my controller.

There would only ever be A-Z a-z 0-9 in-between the brackets.
I will be testing the solutions shown here and give some feedback shortly . Thank you everyone , except for the trolls.

Comment: %^(/*)[^/]+% Seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

This should match the first instance of text that comes between slashes, assuming there are no catches to the question:

```
(?<=\/)[^\/]+(?=\/)
```

Your regex parser should move from left-to-right in your string, and assuming there is no flag to match all instances of the supplied pattern, match only the first instance.  The look-ahead `(?<=...)` and lookbehind `(?=...)` notation will match the supplied characters, but not return them in the matched groups. The character class match of `[^\/]+` will match one or more instances of any character *except* `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only ever lower case letters, this will provide that first part.

```
^/([a-z]+)/.*
```

- The square brackets create a character class, in which the range of letters from a to z are allowed.
- The + after that means there must be one or more instances of this class.
- The surrounding parenthesis means "capture this group", ie this is a bit you want to return.
- The slashes are your literal slashes, helping to position the regex in your string.
- The trailing dot means any character, the star after that means zero or more of the proceeding expression... Ie zero or more of any character.
- The ^ at the start anchors the regex to the beginning of your string... So if this string can occur anywhere in a string, not just at the start, you should remove that bit.

Depending on your programming language, there's likely going to need to be some kind of delimiter that denotes the start and end of your expression, too.

If you need characters in addition to lower case letters, add them to the character class, eg: `^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/.*` will also allow upper case letters and digits.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you match to match the first part of a string that starts with a / and the yank the content until the next / then this should work

```
^/([^/]++)/.*+$
```

Proof of concept in java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String s = "/pig/latin/";
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^/([^/]++)/.*+$");
    final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
pig
```

You may need to escape the forward slashes in other languages.